# Qt Update Pixmap of QGraphicsPixmapItem

Tags: c++, qt

I am using the QGraphicsPixmapItem to show an image on the display. Now, I want to be able to update this image on the fly, but I seem to be running into some issues.

This is the **header** file:

```
class Enemy_View : public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
public:
    Enemy_View(QGraphicsScene &myScene);
    void defeat();
private:
    QGraphicsScene &scene;
    QPixmap image;
}
```

And here is the **cpp** file

```
Enemy_View::Enemy_View(QGraphicsScene &myScene):
    image{":/images/alive.png"}, scene(myScene)
{
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *enemyImage = scene.addPixmap(image.scaledToWidth(20));
    enemyImage->setPos(20, 20);
    this->defeat();
}

void Enemy_View::defeat(void)
{
    image.load(":/images/dead.png");
    this->setPixmap(image);
    this->update();
}
```

SO the idea is that I want to be able to call the `defeat` method on my object, that then edits some attributes and eventually changes the image. However, what I am doing now does not work. The `alive.png` image does display, but does not get updated to the `dead.png` one.

---

## Update 1

As mentioned by Marek R I appear to be replicating a lot of built-in functionality. I tried to clean this up but now nothing is showing up on the scene anymore.

**.h** file

```
class Enemy_View : public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
public:
    Enemy_View(QGraphicsScene &myScene);
    void defeat();

private:
    QGraphicsScene &scene;
    /* Extra vars */
};
```

**.cpp** file

```
Enemy_View::Enemy_View(QGraphicsScene &myScene):
    scene(myScene)
{
    /* This part would seem ideal but doesn't work */
    this->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/alive.png").scaledToWidth(10));
    this->setPos(10, 10);
    scene.addItem(this);

    /* This part does render the images */
    auto *thisEl = scene.addPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/Jackskellington.png").scaledToWidth(10));
    thisEl->setPos(10, 10);
    scene.addItem(this);

    this->defeat();
}

void Enemy_View::defeat(void)
{
    this->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/dead.png"));
}
```

So I removed the `QPixmap`, but I'm not sure whether I can remove the `QGraphicsScene`. In my `cpp`-file you can see I have two versions of the constructor now. The first part, using the `this` seems like an ideal solution, but does not display the image on the screen (even though it does compile without errors). The second version with `thisEl` does render it. What am I doing wrong with the first version?

Comment: Why FGS you are subclassing `QGraphicsPixmapItem`? `QGraphicsPixmapItem` has all functionality you need. And those new fields you have added does nothing, they only try replicate functionality which is already there (but with this implementation it does nothing).

Comment: How do you add your `Enemy_View` to the scene?

Comment: @thuga: well this should be done in the constructor I guess, or should it be done in the class that calls the constructor?

Comment: @arbitter I'd do it from the class that creates the object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why FGS you are subclassing `QGraphicsPixmapItem`? `QGraphicsPixmapItem` has all functionality you need. And those new fields you have added does nothing, they only try replicate functionality which is already there (but with this implementation it does nothing).

This suppose to be something like that:

```
QPixmp image(":/images/alive.png");
QGraphicsPixmapItem *enemyItem = scene.addPixmap(image.scaledToWidth(20));
enemyItem->setPos(20, 20);

// and after something dies
QPixmap dieImage(":/images/dead.png");
enemyItem->setPixmap(dieImage);
```

Comment: I am using a subclass because I need to update the model as well, but I left that code out. I'm not quite sure how to - without replicating a bunch - show the image with a certain position on the `QGraphicsScene`. I have updated my answer to reflect what I changed.