# Qt Update QPixmapItem in QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt

I want to have an image in my main window with the buttons laid out on top of the image. I am using view, scene and pixmap item but when I try to change the pixmap item in the slot function, I crash.

Here is an example of what I have:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //scene, view, pixitem and button are private variables in header
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *pixitem = new QGraphicsPixmapItem;

    pixitem->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/this.png"));
    scene->addItem(pixitem);

    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(view);
    this->connect(button,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(slot()));

    this->setCentralWidget(view);
}

void MainWindow:slot()
{
    pixitem->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/that.png"));
}
```

Possible duplicate but this solution did not work for me:
[Qt Update Pixmap of QGraphicsPixmapItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085166/qt-update-pixmap-of-qgraphicspixmapitem)

Comment: Use a debugger and break, when the application faults. Since you're using signals and slots, you will need to learn how to use a debugger. You'll be using it a lot, as signals and slots **completely** obscure your application's structure.

Comment: ..unlike marvelous function pointers scattered around! :)

Comment: As the answer below suggests, most probably, smth is wrong either with the pixmap item itslef, or the image path. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-5slS2GmOZeZ0t3Q0hOQkl6M0k/view?usp=sharing has a trvial project demonstrating, that with proper initialization, your code works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have shadowed the member variable `pixitem` because you are using

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem *pixitem = new QGraphicsPixmapItem;
```

The `pixitem` added to the scene will be reference by the local variable, not by the member variable. Just change to

```
pixitem = new QGraphicsPixmapItem;
```

Comment: Shadowed is the word :)

Answer (score 3):

In the constructor, you create the pixmap item:

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem *pixitem = new QGraphicsPixmapItem;
```

Then in the slot you call

```
pixitem->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/that.png"));
```

In order to compile successfully, you must have a QGraphicsPixmap* as a member of the class. Therefore, I conclude that this is NULL, or at least, invalid due to the creation of the item on the pointer in the constructor.

Assuming this is correct and you have indeed declared pixitem in the header of the class, change the creation in the constructor to: -

```
pixitem = new QGraphicsPixmapItem;
```

Comment: Shortly, `pixitem` class member is probably shadowed by a local var with the same name (and is accessed uninitialized in the slot).