# To draw some points by using QImage, QWidget.update() is too slow, Is there more faster way?

Tags: qt, qimage

I'm trying to draw a point on the window by using `QImage`, and update the position of this point as fast as possible(less than 1ms every update). I've wrote the code below and run it, but the result is it's too slow(about 50ms every update). I searched the bottleneck and found the cause of this slowness is calling `QWidget.update()` takes too long. So I figured out as long as using `Widget.update()` it won't be faster. So I think I need another way. Is there any faster way to do this? All of the codes and the result are the following.

result:

[image]

qimageBehaviorForStackOverflowQuestion.pro

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (3.1) Wed Mar 29 15:18:09 2017
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = qimageBehaviorForStackOverflowQuestion
INCLUDEPATH += .
QT += widgets

# Input
HEADERS += qimageBehaviorForStackOverflowQuestion.h
SOURCES += qimageBehaviorForStackOverflowQuestion.cpp
```

qimageBehaviorForStackOverflowQuestion.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QImage>
#include <QTime>

class MyWidget : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
 private:
  QImage *image;
  int px, py;
  uchar d[100*100*4];
  QTimer *timer;
  QTime time;
public:
  MyWidget();
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event);
public slots: 
  void doPaint();
};
```

qimageBehaviorForStackOverflowQuestion.cpp

```
#include "qimageBehaviorForStackOverflowQuestion.h"

int my_counter = 0;

MyWidget::MyWidget() : QWidget(0), px(0), py(0){
  image = new QImage(d, 100, 100, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
  for(int cnt = 0, a, r, g, b; cnt < 100*100*4;){
    a = 255; //alpha
    r = 0;   //red
    g = 0;   //green
    b = 0;   //blue

    d[cnt] = b; cnt++;
    d[cnt] = g; cnt++;
    d[cnt] = r; cnt++;
    d[cnt] = a; cnt++;
  }
  // connect QTimer.timeout to my doPaint method
  timer = new QTimer();
  connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(doPaint()));
  timer->start(1);
};

void MyWidget::doPaint(){
  // manipulate the positions of the points
  if(px < 100){
    int cnt = 0, b = 255, g = 255, r = 255, a = 255;
    d[4 * px + cnt] = b; cnt++;
    d[4 * px + cnt] = g; cnt++;
    d[4 * px + cnt] = r; cnt++;
    d[4 * px + cnt] = a; cnt++;
    px++;
  }
  // update the window
  update();
};

void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event){
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawImage(0, 0, *image);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MyWidget *widget = new MyWidget();
  widget->show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried QGraphicsScene?

Comment: @ni1ight: No, I haven't. Is QGraphicsScene hint?

Comment: [Qt Update Pixmap of QGraphicsPixmapItem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085166/qt-update-pixmap-of-qgraphicspixmapitem) It was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

After googling couple of hours, I found more faster way. It becomes incredibly very fast(once 20FPS is now about 500FPS).What I'm using now is `QGraphicsView Framework` and `QPixmap` and `QGraphicsPixmapItem`. However I don't know this is the right or efficient way, if it isn't please correct me. And if you know there is more faster way please let me know. Any way I show you the code. I hope it could help someone who fight same problem.

qgraphicsSceneExample.h

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QGraphicsView>
    #include <QGraphicsScene>
    #include <QGraphicsItem>
    #include <QTimer>
    #include <QPainter>
    #include <QPushButton>
    #include <QImage>
    #include <QTime>
    #include <QStyleOptionGraphicsItem>
    #include <QWidget>
    #include <QPixmap>
    #include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>


    class MyView : public QGraphicsView {
        Q_OBJECT
    private:
        QGraphicsScene *scene;
        QImage *image;
        QPixmap *pixmap;
        QGraphicsPixmapItem *gpixmapItem;
        int px, py;
        uchar d[100*100*4];
        QTimer *timer;
        QTime time;
    public:
        MyView();
        //void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event);
    public slots:
        void doPaint();
    };
```

qgraphicsSceneExample.cpp

```
#include "qgraphicsSceneExample.h"

int my_counter = 0;

MyView::MyView() : px(0), py(0){

    image = new QImage(d, 100, 100, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    for(int cnt = 0, a, r, g, b; cnt < 100*100*4;){
        a = 255; //alpha
        r = 0;   //red
        g = 0;   //green
        b = 0;   //blue

        d[cnt] = b; cnt++;
        d[cnt] = g; cnt++;
        d[cnt] = r; cnt++;
        d[cnt] = a; cnt++;
    }

    // connect QTimer.timeout to my doPaint method
    timer = new QTimer();
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(doPaint()));
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(0);
    pixmap = new QPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*image));
    gpixmapItem = scene->addPixmap(*pixmap);
    this->setScene(scene);

    timer->start(1);
};


void MyView::doPaint(){
    // manipulate the positions of the points
    if(px < 100){
        int cnt = 0, b = 255, g = 255, r = 255, a = 255;
        d[4 * px + cnt] = b; cnt++;
        d[4 * px + cnt] = g; cnt++;
        d[4 * px + cnt] = r; cnt++;
        d[4 * px + cnt] = a; cnt++;
        px++;
    }
    pixmap = new QPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*image));
    gpixmapItem->setPixmap(*pixmap);
    std::cout << my_counter++ << "\n";
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MyView *myView = new MyView();
    myView->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing the incrementation of Px to more than +1, +5 for example. that will reduce the calls of doPaint() function by 5 times. and will speed up the drawing.  Because your problem is that you are updating the drawing a lot, 100 times.

P.S : you should also stop the timer to stop calling doPaint() function when the drawing is finished. because it is called every 1ms. since `timer.start(1)` will emit `timeout()` signal every 1ms.

**Edit:**
Consider also changing the timeout that is very light (an update every 1ms <=> 1000 FPS).

Comment: OK it's true, but I want to know the way increase FPS. Currently about 20 FPS is my limitation... But I don't think it is true limitation.

Comment: it is a limitation. Since your eye take minimum 13 ms to see an image http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2542583/Scientists-record-fastest-time-human-image-takes-just-13-milliseconds.html

Comment: yes. but you can test and see what is best for your app. update() calls the paintEvent and i don't know how much time it takes to draw your widget.